# Android Studio Create Action Bar

Tags: java, android, inheritance, android-studio, android-actionbar

I'm completely new to Android Developement and this is my first day I ever touched Android studio. Just a silly question: I'm implementing a note taking app and in my main view activity I have to do this

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {}
```

but the original code is

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {}
```

MainActivity.java

```
 package com.example.sunny.mynote;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteDataSource;
import com.example.sunny.mynote.com.example.sunny.mynote.data.NoteItem;

import java.util.List;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private NoteDataSource datasource;
    List<NoteItem> notesList;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        datasource = new NoteDataSource(this);

        refreshDisplay();
    }

    private void refreshDisplay() {
        notesList = datasource.findAll();
        ArrayAdapter<NoteItem> adapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<NoteItem>(this, R.layout.list_item_layout, notesList);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        lv.setListAdapter(adapter);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mina.mynote.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

However this makes my action bar disappear, i know I cant inherit MainActivity to ActionBarActivity because Java doesnt support 2 inheritance, so how can I make my action bar appear? Please Help!!

Comment: can you post your layout xml file for the activity?

Comment: ok, can you also post activity_main.xml from your res folder please?

Comment: @HarperMina Create a subclass or inner class which extends ListActivity. This will solve your problem. Leave MainActivity as it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is put a listview inside an ActionBarActivity.  Change `public class MainActivity extends ListActivity` back to `public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity`.  Then you need to change the layout so there's a container for the listview.  You can use relativelayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.mina.mynote.MainActivity">

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then, you need to change this call, where you're setting the adapter:  `setListAdapter(adapter)`.  Your activity is no longer inheriting from ListActivity, so it doesn't have this method.  You need to get a reference to your listview first, and then call `setListAdapter()` on it:

```
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
//setListAdapter becomes setAdapter
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

By the way, consider using something a little less generic/ambiguous than 'list' for your listview id.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please check my newest updates. I followes your suggestions but now get errors Cannot Resolve Symbol for ListView and list, error cannot resolve method for setListAdapter.

Comment: oh -- you need to `import android.widget.ListView;`   Android studio usually prompts you to do that to resolve those unresolved symbol errors...

Comment: You may also need to change the ListView id in the xml to `@+id/list`

Comment: I still got error cannot resolve method for setListAdapter. Dont know why

Comment: whoops -- I just double-checked -- it should be `setAdapter()`, not `setListAdapter()`.  Sorry!

Comment: Hi, just one more issue. Now I want to use onListitemclick but my main Activity does not extend to ListActivity. How can I still use onListitemclick ?

Comment: It's definitely possible. Would you mind creating a separate question post?